# JNDI Connection In Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, jndi

I have added below codes in jdbc.properties present in Pentaho Spoon tool

```
test_conn/type=javax.sql.DataSource
test_conn/driver=org.postgresql.Driver
test_conn/url=jdbc:postgres://dummyurl.com:5432/postgres
test_conn/user=testuser
test_conn/password=12345
```

When selecting JNDI as access method in Pentaho Spoon,I'm getting below error

```
Error connecting to database [Test DB] 
:org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://
```

The credentials are proper as I'm able to connect DB from other sources(PgAdmin)..

Any help how to resolve above error?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the url is `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database` and not `jdbc:postgres://host:port/database`.